# Syntaxt error on gmaps/haml code

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, haml, gmaps4rails

I have this piece of code to show multiple maps on a page:

```
.row
  .span12
    - counter = 1
    - @users.each do |user|
      - map_visits = user.visits.to_gmaps4rails
        - unless map_visits.blank?
          .span3
            %div{ id: "container_#{counter}" }
              %div{ id: "map_#{counter}" }
                = gmaps(map_options: { zoom: 6, container_id: "container_#{counter}", id: "map_#{counter}" }, markers: { data: map_visits } )
                - counter += counter
```

It returns an error "syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting $end", but I can't really figure out what's wrong here. The better_errors gem shows the error on the 3 "container_#{counter}" items in the code. Any ideas?

Comment: I’m not sure if this is what is causing your error, but the line `- unless map_visits.blank?` (and the lines following it) shouldn’t be indented – it should be at the same level as the line before.

Comment: Bingo! Didn't see that one, thank you :-) If you make that the answer, I can give you credit for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You’ve got some unnecessary indentation, the line - `unless map_visits.blank?` (and the lines following it) shouldn’t be indented:

```haml
- map_visits = user.visits.to_gmaps4rails
- unless map_visits.blank?
  .span3
    ...
```